# Cannot update a record in Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following method in the repository and I need to update an Entity.
Unfortunately I cannot update the record (no errors message).

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
    public void Update(GaLocation entity)
    {
        context.GaLocations.Attach(entity);
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you perform a TRACE on the database. Do you see anything get sent to the database?

Comment: is the pk of entity set ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I update entries:

```
public void Update(GaLocation entity)
{
    GaLocation gl = context.GaLocations.Where(h=>h.id == entity.id).FirstOrDefault();
    gl.val1 = entity.val1;
    gl.val2 = entity.val2;
    //etc
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I've tried using `Attach`, but I've run into issues with that too.  I'm sure it works, but this way worked better for me.

Comment: @Dismissile The `gl` context is tracked, so when you update it, then call `.SaveChanges()`, it updates the database because the context knows it has changed.  Similar to: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: OK, I started the answer and got pulled away.  Thx for updating the vote.